# Trying to create an email template without using background-img

Tags: html, css, image, email

I'm having an issue with the `background-image` in css. The problem is I can't use background-image in email templates.
To solve this problem I can use `<img>` tag, the problem is that I have some text to place in front of the image.
So... what I want to know is if there is any option to avoid the use of the background-image, using `<img>` and place some text on the top. Here's my code:

```
<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-width:100%;min-width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;" width="100%" class="mcnTextContentContainer">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" class="mcnTextContent" style="padding-top:0;padding-right:18px;padding-bottom:9px;padding-left:18px;color:#808080;font-family:Helvetica;font-size:16px;line-height:150%;text-align:left;background-color: #003b5d;background:url('http://example.com/images/bg-hero.jpg');">
        <h2 class="null" style="text-align:center;height:100px;color:#FFF;display:block;margin:0;padding:0;font-family:Helvetica;font-size:34px;font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;line-height:150%;letter-spacing:normal;padding-top:50px;">A friendly message</h2>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What I want is to replace the background-image `background:url('http://example.com/images/bg-hero.jpg');`
in the code

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this css can help you out! It's working for my e-mail template.

```
body {

background-image: url('http://example.com/images/bg-hero.jpg');

background-repeat: repeat-y no-repeat;

background-color: #333;

margin: 0;

padding: 0;

}
```

Comment: Working only in Outlook version of only NOT working in outlook version?

Comment: Unfortunately outlook does not support background-images (and a lot of other stuff) due to their Microsoft Office rendering engine.
A list of supported properties per mail client can be found here:
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Hi @MichaelKoelewijn I did read this as well: http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/design/add-a-background-image-to-a-campaign